# Trouble with assigning/calling methods from another class C#

Tags: c#, class

I've looked through other questions but I can't understand what's going on in the answer so I'll post my code here:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Program startUp = new Program();
        Console.Clear();


        string file = @FILEPATH
        string grades = File.ReadAllText(file);                                                                                  
        int acount = grades.Count(c => c == 'A');
        startUp.Grapher();

    }


    public class Graph
    {
        public static string Grapher(int acount)
        {
         Console.WriteLine(String.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("*", acount))); Console.Write(": A");

}}
```

Any help or explanation would be fantastic!

Comment: program.program does not contain a definition for grapher and no extension method grapher accepting a first argument of type program.progam could be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: Also: program.Program.Graph.Grapher(int) not all code paths return a value.  I have other ints in grapher from the main method but haven't put them in here for convenience.

Comment: `Not all code paths return a value` indicates that you're missing a `return` in your `Grapher`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok, from what i see you create a `Program` class instance and then try to use a `Graph` class method.

you should use `Graph` class instance.

```
public static void Main()
{
    Console.Clear();

    string file = @FILEPATH
    string grades = File.ReadAllText(file);                                                                                  
    int acount = grades.Count(c => c == 'A');
    Graph.Grapher(acount);// this is the change

}
```

and the Graph class will be:

```
public class Graph
{
    public static void Grapher(int acount)// the change is here
    {
       Console.WriteLine(String.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("*", acount))); Console.Write(": A");
    }
}
```